# How can I generate a wifi QR code with pillow and qrcode library in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wifi, qr-code

I think there's a way to generate a wifi qr with pillow and qrcode library in Python, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. QR codes are just images that are easy for a computer to decode via taking a picture into something useful.

QR codes are just text/strings encoded into an image.

Python has a library called [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/).

Mobile phone support a specific format of text that tells it to try and connect to a wifi network. This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Joining_a_Wi%E2%80%91Fi_network) shows an example of what that connection string would look like.

So here is the steps.

1. Create a wifi connection string that mobile phones support.
2. Pass that string into qrcode to generate a PIL image.
3. Do what you want with that PIL image.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it

Comment: No problem, if this answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer so it can be closed

Comment: That should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import qrcode


def generate_wifi_qrcode(
    ssid: str,
    password: str,
    security_type="WPA",
    target: str = "wifi_qrcode.png",
) -> None:
    wifi_data = f"WIFI:T:{security_type};S:{ssid};P:{password};;"

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )

    qr.add_data(wifi_data)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    qr_code_image = qr.make_image(
        fill_color="black", back_color="white"
    )

    qr_code_image.save(target)
```